VS2022 WinForms Designer Fails to Load Generic Form Base Class
I'm encountering an issue with Visual Studio 2022 where the WinForms designer fails to load for a generic form base class in a .NET Framework 4.7.2 application. Here's the setup:

Main form: public partial class Form_MainForm : Form_MainForm_Plugin<Plugin>
Base form: public partial class Form_MainForm_Plugin<TPlugin> : Form, IAppUI where TPlugin : class, IPluginInteration

Designer error message:
The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed. The designer inspected the following classes in the file: Form_MainForm --- The base class 'Plugin.Form_MainForm_Plugin`1' could not be loaded. Ensure the assembly has been referenced and that all projects have been built.     

Instances of this error (1)  
1.
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.EnsureDocument(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.BasicDesignerLoader.BeginLoad(IDesignerLoaderHost host) 

I've tried several troubleshooting steps:

Restarting the IDE.
Cleaning the project and rebuilding, followed by an IDE restart.
Changing the solution's target platform from x86 to Any CPU or x64 and rebuilding.
After reviewing solutions from C# generics usercontrol, I tried creating a form (Form_Temp: Form_MainForm_Plugin<Plugin>) and changing Form_MainForm to inherit from Form_Temp.
Commenting out InitializeComponent() in Form_MainForm_Plugin<TPlugin>.
Switching the target framework of the solution to .NET Framework 4.8.

None of these steps resolved the issue, and there are no compilation errors.
Interestingly, this issue does not occur in VS2017 or VS2019. Does anyone have experience with this issue or suggestions on how to resolve it?

sometimes it takes a lot of time to appear, be patient.

@nbk This is a recurring issue I first encountered two years ago and have yet to resolve. Additionally, the designer is not in a loading state; it directly throws an error.

Just a sidenote. Maybe just use an old IDE for an old Framework? As long as you stick with framework 4.8 you don't miss anything presumably.

@Ralf You're absolutely right, but I also have projects on .NET Core, thus I have to frequently switch IDEs instead of just double-clicking to open the .sln file... it's quite frustrating.

You encounter issues with the designer not being able to load generic base forms in WinForms applications which is likely because the Visual Studio designer has limited support for generic classes, especially in .NET Framework. There are some possible solutions:
Solution 1: Use a Non-Generic Intermediate Class
One of the most effective ways to handle this is to use a non-generic intermediate class for the designer, and then inherit from the generic class in your actual form.
// Generic base class
public partial class Form_MainForm_Plugin<TPlugin> : Form where TPlugin : class
{
    public Form_MainForm_Plugin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

// Non-generic intermediate class
public partial class Form_MainForm_NonGeneric : Form_MainForm_Plugin<Plugin>
{
    public Form_MainForm_NonGeneric()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

// Actual derived form
public partial class Form_MainForm : Form_MainForm_NonGeneric
{
    public Form_MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

Solution 2: Use Conditional Compilation Symbols
Another approach is to use conditional compilation symbols to distinguish between design-time and runtime. This way, you can use a non-generic base class for the designer and the generic base class at runtime.
Define a conditional compilation symbol: Add a DESIGN_TIME symbol in your project properties.
Modify the base class definition:
#if DESIGN_TIME
public partial class Form_MainForm_Plugin : Form
{
    public Form_MainForm_Plugin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
#else
public partial class Form_MainForm_Plugin<TPlugin> : Form where TPlugin : class
{
    public Form_MainForm_Plugin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
#endif

